# Mono VBNC crashes for all VB.NET pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ubuntu, mono

I've written a VB.NET forms site in Visual Studio targeting ASP.NET v.3 and have gotten it to work on one of my Ubuntu machines using Mono and it's VBNC compiler.

However, on a fresh install of Ubuntu, after installing all necessary Mono packages (including the latest version of both the runtime and the compiler, I get the same error every time I declare a page's language as VB:

```
Server Error in '/' Application

Compilation Error

Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Compiler Error Message: VBNC_CRASH: Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943 Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved. Error : VBNC99999: Unexpected error: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver
at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at vbnc.Compiler.get_AssemblyResolver () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at vbnc.TypeManager.LoadAssembly (System.String Filename, System.String& FullPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at vbnc.TypeManager.LoadReferencedAssemblies () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at vbnc.TypeManager.LoadReferenced () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at vbnc.Compiler.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Compilation took 00:00:00.2333320

/default.aspx
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

I've tried everything I can imagine - installing all the necessary packages (including mono-complete) and making sure everything's updated. What bothers me is that ANY page (even a hello world) with `<%@ Page Language="VB" %>` causes the compiler to crash. Any page with `<%@ Page Language="C#" %>` works perfectly fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you try to run vbnc from the command line? Just a simple "touch foo.vb && vbnc -target:library foo.vb" should at least work.

Comment: Looks fine to me:
`Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

Assembly 'foo, Version=0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' saved successfully to '/home/nm/foo.dll'.
Compilation successful
Compilation took 00:00:00.9264980`

Since I've posted this question, I've just been precompiling all of my code before pushing it to the server, which works, but I still end up facing all sorts of sporadic errors that should probably not be occuring.

Comment: What if you create a simple vb test.aspx page and start xsp2 in the same directory, and then try "http://localhost:8080/test.aspx"?